# How to use the Rules and Group modules to send a privatemsg to users of a role in a group?

Tags: users, rules, emails, privatemsg, 7

I am using the module [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) with [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) (not [Organic groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og)) as well as the [Privatemsg](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg) module.

I want to send an email to all users of a role that are in a group. I am able to send an email to all users of a role, but I need a Rules condition that sends it to members of a certain group.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Comment #2 in issue # 2603136](https://www.drupal.org/node/2603136#comment-10500028) (from the module maintainer). Here is how it looks like (I added the bold markup in it here):

> Meaning you can already use Rules to:
>
> - Add a new Group
> - Create a new GroupMembership and save it (the equivalent of $group->addMember())
> - Add or remove a GroupRole from a GroupType
> - React on new GroupMembership or Group entities
> - …
>
> What hasn't been done yet is custom Rules actions or conditions. Seeing as 90%+ of Group is pure Entity API CRUD-operations, there has been no custom Rules code yet given how much you can already accomplish out-of-the-box.
>
> Useful Rules we may add could be:
>
> - **E-mail all members of a Group, optionally filtered by GroupRole**
> - Easier-to-understand labels for the above list: "Member joined group" sounds easier than "GroupMembership entity is created"
> - Feel free to add here

As per the bold phrase above, I think the exact answer to your question is "Such Rules condition is not available ... yet".

## Plan B

However, since you're also using the [Privatemsg](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg) module, you may want to have a look at the community documentation about [Privatemsg-Rules Integration](https://www.drupal.org/node/740366), especially the child page about [Introduction to Privatemsg-Rules](https://www.drupal.org/node/880888): it lists the various [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) Events, Conditions and Actions you have available.

More important in the context of this question, is what's explained in the child page "[Message notification via email depending on user's role](https://www.drupal.org/node/880914)".
See where I'm going ...? No? Well: if you can think of a way to assign a role that corresponds to the name of the group (so 1 role for each role), you have an alternative solution that functionally will do exactly what you want to do. Obviously, 1 role for each "group" is only manageable if you don't have dozens (or hundreds?) of groups ...

**Note**: I haven't checked it yet, but it may well be possible to use the Rules module to auto-assign such role automatically when a user gets granted access to a group (Homework for you? Or ask a new question?).